# Add separator to first cell only in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a special table where most elements would look odd with separators so I have disabled them. However, I'd still like the first cell to have a separator. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `UITableViewCell` class for your first cell, and override `drawRect:` in order to draw a line in the bottom (or wherever you want the sepparator)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [_lineColor CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, _lineHeight);

    // Bottom line
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution. This actually makes the line stay when you scroll up and down.

Comment: @dimgl: Please accept the answer if it has solved your problem.